# Excel Using Dates

Tags: excel, date, if-statement

Essentially, all I'm trying to do is check if the cell is empty, then return an empty cell, otherwise, i want to return a date that is 21 days ahead of the date in the cell. Here is what I have so far:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A:A), "", (DATE(YEAR(A:A),MONTH(A:A),DAY(A:A)+21)))
```

However, for and example cell in col A: 12/18/2015, this function will return 42377

Answer (score 1):

42377 is the good result, just it's not formatted as date.

- either you can convert it to text as suggested by Scott Davies, but this case you won't be able to perform further calculations on it
- another way is to just leave your formula as it is; then select the whole column and change its `number formatting` to date.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:
=IF(ISBLANK(A:A), "",TEXT(A:A  + 21, "dd mmm yyyy"))

Obviously this is an array formula so use CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to complete.

Comment: In response to Mate's comment, formatting the output column as date is the better way to do it but what I found is that even if column A is formatted as text and the value is entered as text (eg ="12 Dec 2015"), I was able to do date type formulas on the output of my formula.  I guess excel just has the built in intelligence to figure this out.